# MVC Forms authentication - IsAuthenticated is false after login and true while redirecting explicitly

Tags: asp.net-mvc, cookies, authentication, forms-authentication

I have the following methods responsible for login authentication:

```
 [HttpPost]
    [AllowAnonymous]
    [ValidateAntiForgeryToken]
    public ActionResult Login(LoginModel loginModel, string returnUrl)
    {
        if (ModelState.IsValid)
        {
            //if (Membership.ValidateUser(loginModel.UserName, loginModel.Password))
            var session = RMWebClientBL.Sessions.Login(loginModel.UserName, loginModel.Password);
            if(session != null && !session.IsFailed && session.SessionId != Guid.Empty)
            {
                SetAuthCookie(loginModel, session);
                RedirectToLocal(returnUrl);
            }
            else
            {
                ModelState.AddModelError("", "The user name or password provided is incorrect.");
            }
        }

        // If we got this far, something failed, redisplay form
        return View();
    }

    private void SetAuthCookie(LoginModel loginModel, DomainObjects.Sessions.SessionDetails session)
    {
        // create encryption cookie         
        FormsAuthenticationTicket authTicket = new FormsAuthenticationTicket(1,
                loginModel.UserName,
                DateTime.Now,
                //TODO: make it configurable!!!!
                DateTime.Now.AddMinutes(20),
                loginModel.RememberMe,
                session.SessionId.ToString());

        // add cookie to response stream         
        string encryptedTicket = FormsAuthentication.Encrypt(authTicket);
        System.Web.HttpCookie authCookie = new System.Web.HttpCookie(FormsAuthentication.FormsCookieName, encryptedTicket);
        if (authTicket.IsPersistent)
        {
            authCookie.Expires = authTicket.Expiration;
        }
        System.Web.HttpContext.Current.Response.Cookies.Add(authCookie);  
    }

    private ActionResult RedirectToLocal(string returnUrl)
    {
        if (Url.IsLocalUrl(returnUrl))
        {

           return Redirect(returnUrl);
        }
        else
        {
            return RedirectToAction("Index", "Home");
        }
    }
```

However when i am trying to login "User.Identity.IsAuthenticated" is still false after setting the cookie, BUT it seems that i am logged in because if i am clikcing on our logo which redirects me to the Homepage i am authenticated.
why i am not being able to redirect after logging in?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Found the solution it was a silly thing after all:
the problem was on the following method:

```
  public ActionResult Login(LoginModel loginModel, string returnUrl)
    {
        if (ModelState.IsValid)
        {
            //if (Membership.ValidateUser(loginModel.UserName, loginModel.Password))
            var session = RMWebClientBL.Sessions.Login(loginModel.UserName, loginModel.Password);
            if(session != null && !session.IsFailed && session.SessionId != Guid.Empty)
            {
                SetAuthCookie(loginModel, session);
                return RedirectToLocal(returnUrl);
            }
            else
            {
                ModelState.AddModelError("", "The user name or password provided is incorrect.");
            }
        }

        // If we got this far, something failed, redisplay form
        return View();
    }
```

as you can see i've added "return" to

```
return RedirectToLocal(returnUrl);
```

the problem was that the "return" keyword missing so i always got to  the last row which is :

```
return View();
```

thats way i was always getting back to my login page while not addressing the right page.

Answer (score 0):

Just by looking it doesn't look like you're using the standard MembershipProvider that is included in .NET, as it is this provider that sets the IsAuthenticated flag.  It appears you using your own provider but just using the FormsAuthenticationTicket part only.

Comment: Thats is true, is it wrong? how come after logging and clicking on the logo (which redirects to my home page) the User.Identity.IsAuthenticated is true? that means that it works just not on the first time...

Answer (score 0):

Try use the following method instead of encrypting and create your own cookie.

```
  FormsAuthentication.SetAuthCookie(userAuth, model.RememberMe);
```

The method doesn't just encrypt the ticket, but it also create a cookie, add it to the response and some other things behind the scene. I am using this in my project and it's working perfectly fine.

Comment: Same result. Could it be that due to the fact i am doing everything in post method i have some kind of race condition between assigning the cookie and redirecting?

Comment: I assume you have the web configuration in place?               <authentication mode="Forms">
      <forms loginUrl="~/Account/Index" timeout="1000000" />
    </authentication>

Comment: I see, i was focusing on the fact that u mention "User.Identity.IsAuthenticated" is false ..never mind